# Custom themes that won't work when theme is changed

Tags: theme-development, advanced-custom-fields

I am building a couple custom themes from previously designed and developed sites.  I developed them and will be maintaining as well.  As I am sort of new at custom theming I always hear that I should put the content in the editor so it's in the database in case of a theme switch.

I am setting up these sites using advanced custom fields so those areas are lost on a theme switch already.  If I have no intention of putting these themes out for use or switching do I need to be that concerned about making sure they will work on any theme?

Comment: Advanced Custom Fields data is not deleted when you change themes or even delete field groups.

Comment: I know the acf data is not deleted, I’m just missing something as to why my pages aren’t showing up. I’m using page-$slug for these few pages.... is this my issue. The other themes are getting through the hierarchy to page.php.